PGN extract questions
My main question is if I am using pgn extract along with pgn extract interface, how can I get standard games from a database that has bullet, and blitz games? I am very savvy with the command lines.
My second sub-question is that I am using a pgn extract with a size of 688kb and an interface of 47kb. I feel like they are old, but I don't have a way to check the version number, and I was wondering if either has been updated.
Thanks again for the excellent program.

Some use might be looking at the official webpage
https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/djb/pgn-extract/
In particular, look at flags, eg

--version - print current version number and exit.
TimeControl Matching with -t (https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/djb/pgn-extract/help.html )


I have seen the site and tried to use the command lines, but with disastrous results. The interface was invaluable and generally allowed me to do what I needed. In this case, I was curious if I was missing something on the interface that would allow me to do what I needed.

If you would like to describe what you are trying to do, we might be able to advise on the command-line options to help you out.

Hello I wanted to download a database from lichess. I wanted to sort the database 2400+ for both, games over 20 moves, only wins for white and black, and only standard games. I was trying to do this using pgn extract interface but was struggling. Thanks for the help
